# [pandas]Dividing all elements of columns in df with elements in another column (Same df)

Tags: pandas

I'm sorry, I know this is basic but I've tried to figure it out myself for 2 days by sifting through documentation to no avail.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

name = ["bob","bobby","bombastic"]
age = [10,20,30]
price = [111,222,333]
share = [3,6,9]

list = [name,age,price,share]
list2 = np.transpose(list)

dftest = pd.DataFrame(list2, columns = ["name","age","price","share"])
print(dftest)

        name age price share
0        bob  10   111     3
1      bobby  20   222     6
2  bombastic  30   333     9
```

**Want to divide all elements in 'price' column with all elements in 'share' column. I've tried**:

```
print(dftest[['price']/['share']]) - Failed

dftest['price']/dftest['share'] - Failed, unsupported operand type

dftest.loc[:,'price']/dftest.loc[:,'share'] - Failed
```

---

**Wondering if I could just change everything to int or float, I tried:**

```
dftest.astype(float) - cant convert from str to float
```

Ive tried **iter** and items methods but could not understand the printouts...

My only suspicion is to use something called iterate, which I am unable to wrap my head around despite reading other old posts...

Please help me T_T

Comment: `df['price']/df['shre]` This is the correct way to write column-to-column calculations.

Comment: Doesnt work, unsupported operand type for str and str

Comment: What is the `df.dtypes` output?

Comment: 'dftest[['price', 'share']].astype(int)`　Convert it to an integer and then execute it in the previous way.

Comment: name     object
age      object
price    object
share    object
dtype: object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies in advance for the somewhat protracted answer, but the question is somewhat unclear with regards to what exactly you're attempting to accomplish.

If you simply want price[0]/share[0], price[1]/share[1], etc. you can just do:

```
dftest['price_div_share'] = dftest['price'] / dftest['share']
```

The issue with the operand types can be solved by:

```
dftest['price_div_share'] = dftest['price'].astype(float) / dftest['share'].astype(float)
```

You're getting the `cant convert from str to float` error because you're trying to call `astype(float)` on the ENTIRE dataframe which contains string columns.

If you want to divide each item by each item, i.e. price[0] / share[0], price[1] / share[0], price[2] / share[0], price[0] / share[1], etc. You would need to iterate through each item and append the result to a new list. You can do that pretty easily with a for loop, although it may take some time if you're working with a large dataset. It would look something like this if you simply want the result:

```
new_list = []
for p in dftest['price'].astype(float):
    for s in dftest['share'].astype(float):
        new_list.append(p/s)
```

If you want to get this in a new dataframe you can simply save it to a new dataframe using  pd.Dataframe() method:

```
new_df = pd.Dataframe(new_list, columns=[price_divided_by_share])
```

This new dataframe would only have one column (the result, as mentioned above). If you want the information from the original dataframe as well, then you would do something like the following:

```
new_list = []
for n, a, p in zip(dftest['name'], dftest['age'], dftest['price'].astype(float):
    for s in dftest['share'].astype(float):
        new_list.append([n, a, p, s, p/s])

new_df = pd.Dataframe(new_list, columns=[name, age, price, share, price_div_by_share])
```

Comment: The 2nd code worked!  (Accidentally pressed enter for prev comment)
The 3rd code cant convert from str to str...strange. I've tested it seperately on a more basic list and it worked.

But you (@as_owl) and @sammywemmy replies pointed out something to me...my datatype is the problem. I have tried changing the datatypes using    dftest.astype(int)    on the columns I want, but the result isnt being saved when checked via dftest.dtypes.

On your 4th and 5th code, I will need time to break it down to understand and apply accordingly. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Its okay I figured out how to store the new type. Had to use samelist[samecolumn] = samelist[samecolumn].astype(int).

Comment: I edited the for loop to insure that it works, adding `astype(float)` to the relevant columns in the loop.

Comment: Tested all and it works, with new nuances learnt from your codes I managed to tweak 5th code accordingly to work! Can't thank you enough man!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If you check the data types of your dataframe, you will realise that they are all `strings/object` type :

```
dftest.dtypes
name     object
age      object
price    object
share    object
dtype: object
```

first step will be to change the relevant columns to numbers - this is one way:

```
dftest = dftest.set_index("name").astype(float)

dftest.dtypes
age      float64
price    float64
share    float64
dtype: object
```

This way you make the names a useful index, and separate it from the numeric data. This is just a suggestion; you may have other reasons to leave names as a columns - in that case, you have to individually change the data types of each column.

Once that is done, you can safely execute your code :

```
dftest.div(dftest.share,axis=0)


              age   price   share
name            
bob         3.333333    37.0    1.0
bobby       3.333333    37.0    1.0
bombastic   3.333333    37.0    1.0
```

I assume this is what you expect as your outcome. If not, you can tweak it. Main part is get your data types as numbers before computation/division can occur.

Comment: Not the result I intended but I did not even know you could divide like that across the entire row, thanks.